# Incompatible pointer type initializing 'CustomCellView *' with an expression of type UItableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios4

Can you help me understandand/fix the error below. I don't understand as `CustomCellView` is a subclass of `UItableViewCell`. The code gets compiled but the warning is still there:

```
Incompatible pointer type initializing 'CustomCellView *' with an expression of type `UItableViewCell`
```

I got the 2nd line below hightlighted:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCellView *cell =(CustomCellView*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

**you need to type cast to your cell**

Answer (score -1):

For custom cell below code is also working fine with given frame..

```
  CustomCell *cell= [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
CustomCellView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.